# Android GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING always zero

Tags: android, glsurfaceview, egl

I'm trying to write a custom GL surface view, I have a problem when trying to get sampleCount or frameBuffers, always return as zero.

I added the following to manifest as well, but nothing works:
- android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
- uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"

Here is the code I'm using:

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    // get the config
    EGL10 egl = (EGL10)EGLContext.getEGL();
    javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLDisplay disp = egl.eglGetCurrentDisplay();

    // stencil buffers
    int[] stencilBuffers = new int[1];
    boolean check = egl.eglGetConfigAttrib(disp, config, EGL10.EGL_STENCIL_SIZE, stencilBuffers); // stencilBuffers[0] = 8

    // samples
    int[] samples = new int[1];
    check = egl.eglGetConfigAttrib(disp, config, EGL10.EGL_SAMPLES, samples); // samples[0]

    // get the frame buffer
    int[] frameBuffers = new int[1];
    gl.glGetIntegerv(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, frameBuffers, 0); // frameBuffers[0] = 0
```